# How to join sub-query in laravel elequent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do this query in laravel query builder ?

```
select * from products p join 

(
select product_id,sum(qty) total_sales 

from orders where qty !=0 group by product_id
) 

s on p.id = s.product_id

order by s.total_sales desc
```

Comment: You can make a [raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways are there to do the same thing. But you can do with [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions) is very similar to your above code.

Comment: for your question one to?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Eloquent, Do this provided the orders table has product_id that is a foreign key from products

```
DB::table('products')->join('orders','products.id','orders.product_id')->where('orders.qty','!=',0)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part for sub-query for `join`ed part. It is joined with `toSql()` method inside the `raw` statement.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('qty', '!=', DB::raw(0))
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->select('product_id', DB::raw('sum(qty) as total_sales'));

return DB::table('products as p')
    ->join(DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql() . ') s'), 'p.id', '=', 's.product_id')
    ->orderByDesc('s.total_sales')
    ->get();
```

It prints the following sql;

```
SELECT *
FROM `products` AS `p`
         INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `product_id`, SUM(qty) AS total_sales
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `qty` != 0
    GROUP BY `product_id`
) s ON `p`.`id` = `s`.`product_id`
ORDER BY `s`.`total_sales` DESC
```